# Custom made javascript function(inheritence example)

Tags: javascript

How do I access array first element by custom made function which will work as a built in function like array.pop()?

Say if I have an array 
var arr=[1,2,3,4] and I want to have a function like arr.first() which will return me an array which will be having first element inside it like [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can augment any array instance with `Array.prototype`.

```
Array.prototype.first = function() { return this[0]; };
```

However, it is strongly discouraged to modify the built in types.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .slice(0,1)
```

or

```
 [ array[0] ]
```

i dont think theres a need for an inbuilt function.

Comment: It think OP wants to learn how to work with `prototype` and how to extend it

Comment: @igor then he shouldnt start with native prototypes.